# Get start and End location and Date Sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

i want to convert this query to start GRP to End Grp and Start Date to End date.

```
select * from (
 select z.ZoneGroupId, zs.ObjectId,z.Name,case when zs.Inside=0 then 'Left' else 'Entered' end Crossing ,zs.TimeFirst
from  zs join 
 z on zs.Zid=z.Zid
where zs.ObjectId=5696 and    z.ZoneGroupId in (1095,1096) and convert(date,zs.TimeFirst)>='2016/07/01'     ) s
where   (ZoneGroupId=1096 and s.Crossing='Entered') or (ZoneGroupId=1095 and s.Crossing='Left')
```

2 table involve in query

table Z

```
  Zid(int)   Name(varchar)  ZoneGroupId (int)
   59         Oil            1095
   60         ENR            1096
   61         NRL            1096
```

table Zs

```
  zsid(int)  zid(int)  ObjectId(int)   Timefirst(datetime)  Inside(boolan)

    1         60         1988           2016-07-01 00:39      1
    2         59         1988           2016-07-05 15:47      0         
    3         61         1988           2016-07-06 22:54      1      
    4         59         1988           2016-07-09 13:40      0         
    5         60         1988           2016-07-10 07:58      1      
    6         59         1988           2016-07-13 10:30      0         
    7         59         1988           2016-09-10 10:21      0     
    8         59         1990           2016-07-05 15:47      0         
    9         61         1990           2016-07-06 22:54      1
```

the result which i required from above query

```
  ZoneGroupId   ObjectId  Name   Crossing         TimeFirst
    1096        1988      ENR     Entered        2016-07-01 00:39
    1095        1988      Oil     Left           2016-07-05 15:47
    1096        1988      NRL     Entered        2016-07-06 22:54
    1095        1988      Oil     Left           2016-07-09 13:40
    1096        1988      ENR     Entered        2016-07-10 07:58
    1095        1988      Oil     Left           2016-07-13 10:30
    1095        1988      Oil     Left           2016-09-10 10:21
    1095        1990      Oil     Left           2016-07-05 15:47
    1096        1990      NRL     Entered        2016-07-06 22:54
```

required result

```
 ObjectId  StartName     StartDate            EndName     EndDate
 1988      Null           Null                 ENR      2016-07-01 00:39
 1988      Oil          2016-07-05 15:47       NRL      2016-7-06 22:54
 1988      Oil          2016-07-09 13:40       ENR      2016-07-10 07:58
 1988      Oil          2016-07-13 10:30       Null        Null
 1988      Oil          2016-09-10 10:21       Null        Null
 1988      Oil          2016-07-05 15:47       NRL      2016-7-06 22:54
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include details of relation between strGrp &  EndGrp and StartDT & EndDT in your desired output.

Comment: @GauravRajput table structure is mention now. strGrp and EndGrp is Name column in Z table and TimeFirst column in  Zs table . Time first is startDt and EndDT

Comment: @ZoharPeled question update now

Comment: What data is in the 2 tables to start with? What are the data types on each column (is Zid an int, char - what?)

Comment: Ddl + dml means create table and insert statements.

Comment: Also zs.Inside and zs.ZoneId are in your query, but not in your table definition above!

Comment: @BeanFrog question update now

Comment: @ZoharPeled question update now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your sample data - please include this in your question in future.

```
declare @z table (Zid int, Name nvarchar(3), ZoneGroupId int);
insert into @z values
(59, 'Oil', 1095),
(60, 'ENR', 1096),
(61, 'NRL', 1096);

declare @zs table(zsid int, zid int, ObjectId  int, Timefirst datetime, Inside bit);
insert into @zs values
(   1, 60, 1988,   '2016-07-01 00:39', 1),
(    2, 59, 1988,   '2016-07-05 15:47', 0 ),
(    3, 61, 1988,   '2016-07-06 22:54', 1 ),
(    4, 59, 1988,   '2016-07-09 13:40', 0 ),
(    5, 60, 1988,   '2016-07-10 07:58', 1 ),
(    6, 59, 1988,   '2016-07-13 10:30', 0 ),
(    7, 59, 1988,   '2016-09-10 10:21', 0  ),
(    8, 59, 1990,   '2016-07-05 15:47', 0 ),
(    9, 61, 1990,   '2016-07-06 22:54', 1 );
```

Then, I split the data into 2 tables, `left` and `entered` by using common-table-expressions. Add in a row number to put them in order by time.

Join the tables back together with a full outer join (to get all rows from both sides). The specify the following criteria on the join:

1. ObjectIds match
2. Entered.TimeFirst is the smallest one that is bigger than Left.TimeFirst
3. Left.TimeFirst is the largest one that is smaller than entered.TimeFirst

I also added an order by for clarity. Here is the query.

```
with entered as (
    select z.ZoneGroupId
         , zs.ObjectId
         , z.Name
         , 'Entered' Crossing
         , zs.TimeFirst
         , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ObjectID order by zs.TimeFirst) row_no
    from @zs zs 
    inner join @z z on zs.Zid=z.Zid
    where zs.Inside <> 0 and (z.ZoneGroupId = 1096 and convert(date,zs.TimeFirst)>='2016/07/01')
), [left] as (
    select z.ZoneGroupId
         , zs.ObjectId
         , z.Name
         , 'Left' Crossing
         , zs.TimeFirst
         , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ObjectID order by zs.TimeFirst) row_no
    from @zs zs 
    inner join @z z on zs.Zid=z.Zid
    where zs.Inside = 0 and (z.ZoneGroupId = 1095 and convert(date,zs.TimeFirst)>='2016/07/01')
)
select * 
from [left] 
full outer join entered 
    on entered.row_no = (select MIN(row_no) from entered e
                          where e.TimeFirst > [left].TimeFirst
                          and e.ObjectId = [left].ObjectId)
    and [left].row_no = (select max(row_no) from [left] l
                          where l.TimeFirst < entered.TimeFirst
                          and l.ObjectId = entered.ObjectId)
    and [left].ObjectId = [entered].ObjectId
order by isnull([left].ObjectId,entered.ObjectId), ISNULL([left].TimeFirst,entered.TimeFirst)
```